# How to close/hide app main window?

Tags: uwp

I have an app that has a main window and secondary windows.

In certain situations, I would like to only display a secondary window when the user launches the app.

The problem is that the app's main window is automatically launched, so I after programamtically opening the secondary window I am left with both the main and secondary windows.

Is there any way I can hide the main window?  (Ie, emulate the user pressing the "close button" in the top right corner of the main window?)

Comment: Couldn't you just show the content of the secondary window in the main window?

Comment: Yep, I could.  I'd rather not because the user should be able to open the main window explicitly later, in which case I'd have to transfer the secondary window content from the main view to a new secondary view.  I'll probably end up doing this if I don't figure out how to hide the main window :)

Comment: Why transfering? You could've just show another window (secondary) and call it the main. :D Or is this impossible because of something else?

Comment: Hm, that could just work :P  Right now the main window loads `MainPage.xaml` and secondary windows load `SecondaryPage.xaml`, but I guess I could abstract that away and not differentiate between main and secondary windows.

Comment: @MarianDolinský So I just ended up using your suggestion :P  I show the content I want in the main window.  Later, when the user wants the main window content I create a secondary window and show the main content there.  If you chuck your content in an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why closing/hiding the main window? You could show the content of the secondary window in the main window (that is created when app's launched) and if user wants to show the main window you could show its content in secondary window.

Answer (score 2):

After creating the secondary view I switch to this new view specifying the `fromViewId` as the main view id, and using the `ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.ConsolidateViews` option, which hides it:

```
// Create seprate secondary window
await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(secondaryWindowViewId);

// Switch to secondary window just created, which hides the main view
await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(
    secondaryWindowViewId, 
    mainWindowViewId, 
    ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.ConsolidateViews);
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works :)  More elegant solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Execute `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryConsolidateAsync()` in main window to close it properly as if you have closed it by clicking close button in title bar. This is preferred over `Application.Exit()` as this method suspends the app while `Application.Exit()` closes app abruptly. Also closing app by this method your app's previous position and size is remembered unlike for `Application.Exit()`.